# How do I write a preseed file to exactly reproduce a default server build?

Tags: server, system-installation, preseed

I'm trying to provision a batch of virtual servers. They are 100% nothing special - I go through the default install selecting English/UK, primary network eth0, hostname, default user, regular entire-disk partitioning, and only add openssh-server.

But when I try to set up a preseed file to do this (https://gist.github.com/pfmoore/2a34b3396a95d767205c) and a boot command line of

```
/install/vmlinuz url=http://example.com/basic.cfg locale=en_GB \
keymap=gb interface=eth0 hostname=XXX \
debconf/frontend=noninteractive debian-installer/keymap=gb \
initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet --
```

it's never *quite* the same. The hostname is "localhost" even though i set it on the boot command line. When I log in, I don't get the landscape "System Information" banner. The output of `dpkg -l` is 45 packages shorter (there's some basic stuff like vim, curl, tmux missing)...

I'm aware that I can do `debconf-get-selections --installer` to query the "right" values, but that doesn't give me something maintainable (or even readable, TBH...).

I've searched the web and found lots of advice on how to set up unusual configurations, but I haven't been able to find anything that explains how to set up the basic, out-of-the-box default configuration.

So - how do I set up an unattended default installation? (I'm happy to ignore any non-default selections in the above just to get a starting point, although advice on how to include those would also be welcome).